# Animating background-position via keyframes not working on Webkit

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, css-animations

I cannot figure out why animations of background-position aren't working on my version of Chrome of Safari (Webkit Browsers). It's working fine on Firefox.

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  to {
    background-position: 100% 0px; } 
}

.logo {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300");
  background-position: 0px 0px;

  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkeMitchll/kpBby/2/

Any help greatly appreciated!.

LM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix `@keyframes` with the browser-specific prefix "-webkit" as well, see [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px; }

  to {
    background-position: 100% 0px; } 
}
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kpBby/3/